# Relation between side and radius of circle without any trigonometric functions

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

We have an equilateral triangle with 3 circles of equal radii inscribed in it. How do we find a relation between the side length "a" of the triangle and radius "r" of the circles? With trigonometric knowledge, mainly 30-60-90 triangles, the question is pretty straightforward, but how does one go about it purely from a geometric viewpoint. I got my answer as a = 2r(1 + $\sqrt{3}$).
But have no clue about how to approach the problem without trig.

Answer (score 1):

Using $30°-60°-90°$ triangles:

$$2\sqrt 3r+2r=a$$

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

### "Purely Geometric"

Since the given figure is an equilateral triangle, you will need to use the $60°$ angles somehow. Let's assume you don't know any trigonometry. Let's prove the side length ratios of $30-60-90$ triangles purely geometrically.

Suppose we have a $30-60-90$ triangle with only $HC$ equal to $k$ (in the below figure). When you stick a copy of this triangle next to the original you form an equilateral triangle (all angles are $60°$). Therefore, we know $AC=2k$ and we can apply Pythagorean Theorem in $AHC$ to obtain $AH= r \sqrt3$.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Comment: Again, 30-60-90 triangles stem from trigonometric properties, so this. wouldn't count

Comment: @Alzebrian Sorry I hadn't read your question properly. However, technically, you could simply stick two 30-60-90 triangles to each other, forming an equilateral triangle. Then, you can deduce that the height is $r \sqrt3$ from Pythagorean Theorem. Nearly everything you do using trigonometry can be simply done using geometry. What you ask for doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. I basically need to find the equation you found without using any trigonometric properties. I tried playing around with the height of the triangle, but couldn't find the relation. If you could elaborate on your idea.

Comment: @Alzebrian I edited my answer accordingly.